# Missing Quarter in Form No 16

Tags: income-tax, mortgage, india

My previous employer has mistakenly no mentioned the Q3 in my Form 16, but it has the details of Q2 and Q4. I have applied for a home loan and the bank wants it clear. But the problem is that the management of my previous employer has changed and it is all a messy situation. please guide me on this.

Comment: Any reason to use form 16. Ideally the financial institutions ask for IT Returns.

Answer (score 1):

Use IT department generated 26AS and form 16. That will have the details of all TDS and net income and taxable for the year.

Answer (score 1):

It's not mandatory to pay TDS in all quarters. It's not an issue. Overall tax paid on your TDS statement should match with your payable tax of the year.

If your Q2 and Q4 total are matching with your total tax payable. Then good to go :)